# Mensagem de "Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed" no meu console

Tags: php, angularjs

Estou usando angular e php.
A seguinte mensagem aparece no meu console:

> Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: mensagem in mensagens, Duplicate key: string:r, Duplicate value: r

Não estou usando "track by $index" no meu arquivo html, pois dá outro problema e bem doido kkkkk

html:

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="mensagem in mensagens track by id">
   <div class="item item-text-wrap">
     <h2>{{mensagem.nome}}</h2>
     <p> {{mensagem.msg}}</p>
     <p>{{mensagem.hora}}</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

angular:

```
.controller('logradouroCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $window) {

var pegaMsgsLogra = function () {
    idCep = $window.localStorage.getItem('idCep');
    idUsuario = $window.localStorage.getItem('idUsuario');
    var dados = {
        idUsuario: $window.localStorage.getItem('idUsuario'),
        idCep: $window.localStorage.getItem('idCep')
    }

    $http.post("http://www.vigilantescomunitarios.com/www/php/pegaMsgsLogra.php", dados).success(function (data){
        $scope.mensagens = data;
    });
}

pegaMsgsLogra();

$scope.enviarMsg = function (msg) {
    var enviaMsg = {
        msg: msg,
        idUsuario: $window.localStorage.getItem('idUsuario'),
        idCep: $window.localStorage.getItem('idCep'),
        nome: $window.localStorage.getItem('nome')
    }

    $http.post("http://www.vigilantescomunitarios.com/www/php/enviaMsgLogra.php", enviaMsg).success(function (data){

        console.log(data);
    });
    pegaMsgsLogra();
}

})
```

php:

```
while ($linhaMsg=$pegaMsgsLogra->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    @$idAviso = $linhaMsg['idAvisoLogradouro'];
    @$idUsuario = $linhaMsg['idUsuario'];
    @$msg = $linhaMsg['msg'];
    @$foto = utf8_encode($linhaMsg['foto']);
    @$hora = $linhaMsg['hora'];

    $horaP = explode(':', $hora);
    $hora = $horaP[0].':'.$horaP[1];

    //Busca nome do usuário que envio a mensagem
    $pegaUsuarioRemetente=$pdo->prepare("SELECT nome FROM usuarios WHERE idUsuario=:idUsuario");
    $pegaUsuarioRemetente->bindValue("idUsuario", $idUsuario);
    $pegaUsuarioRemetente->execute();

    while ($linhaUsuarioRemetente=$pegaUsuarioRemetente->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $nomeRemetente  = utf8_encode($linhaUsuarioRemetente['nome']);

    $return = array(
            'id' => $idAviso,
            'nome' => $nomeRemetente,
            'msg' => $msg,
            'foto' => $foto,
            'hora' => $hora
        );

    $mensagens[] = $return;

    }

}

print_r($mensagens);
echo json_encode($mensagens);
```

Comment: Tente adicionar `track by mensagem.id"` no seu ng-repeat. Ex: `ng-repeat="mensagem in mensagens track by mensagem.id"`

Comment: Não adiantou @Techies.

Comment: apareceu algum erro? você tem um identificador dentro de cada objeto da lista?

Comment: Só id, que acabei de colocar, mas tb não adiantou... Esperai que vou atualizar os códigos aqui no post

Comment: Coloque como está seu Json tb e os erros

Comment: Tentou dar uma olhada na doc? https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes

Comment: Se o track by não adiantou, seu json deve estar inválido. Qual o log do objeto retornado?

Comment: Ou então tente `track by $index`

Comment: @GustavoSevero, como o CelsomTrindade comentou, pode ser que o json seja inválido, das vezes que já vi esse tipo de mensagem, bem semelhante ao seu.. em meu projeto, sempre foi json inválido